# Does bicycling improve abs?

Tags: abdominals, bicycling

I have been noticing recently that my abdominal area (over the stomach) has been getting really firm.
I think it is the abdominal muscles.

I have been bycycling fairly hard for about an hour every weekday for the least 18 months.
Its about the only serious exercise I get.

I didn't expect it to strengthen my abs.
I have been getting the expected thigh muscles, and had noticeable change in <6 months.

I'm getting slightly concerned about the firmness.
If it isn't exercise improving the muscles it may be some kind of medical issue, which warrants looking into.

Comment: It's quite possibly the cycling, as you will use both abdominals and back muscles for stability. The harder your efforts, the more you will tend to tense those muscles to counterbalance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes - for two reasons (probably).**

1.) Biking will burn calories and unless you're eating more calories to compensate, you'll be losing fat, thus feeling more tight in your stomach area.

2.) Your core muscles (aka your abs and others) are involved in practically EVERY movement you do to varying degrees. If you haven't exercised much in the past, you'll probably see some growth in your core-strength.